# Prove that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not have any roots in common.

Tags: polynomials, roots, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose that $a(x)f(x) +b(x)g(x) = 135$ where $a(x), b(x), f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials over $F$.  Prove that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ do not have any roots in common.

Any help is appreciated; thanks!

Comment: What is $F{}{}$?

Comment: @EricWofsey A field

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is not true then.

Comment: @EricWofsey Wait why is my answer incorrect?

Comment: @Ovi: 135 could be 0.

Comment: @EricWofsey Ah if the characteristic of the field divides $135$, right?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there was a root in common $\alpha$ and plug it into your identity.